# how can i replace vuex with apollo client state managment?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I'm new for apollo-client and I wanted to replace vuex for state management keeping that in mind is there any way I can put my mutations and queries in a centralized way as vuex does? most tutorials and documents I found, call queries and mutations in each component which may cause repetition of queries and mutation so how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't have a ton of Vuex experience, but I have a production app using Vue Apollo, and it's really a different mindset.

Apollo isn't a local **store** of data, it's a structured way of accessing **remote** data. It's more a substitute for Axios than for Vuex.

In the case of Apollo, repeating a query isn't a bad thing, because Apollo has a pretty smart **caching** strategy. You can call queries with `fetchPolicy: 'cache-first'` to direct Apollo not to refetch already fetched data.

(Now, if data is frequently changing -- such as in a chat app -- you may *not* want to only rely on cached data. That's a decision you make on a query-by-query basis.)

That said, I would **not** use Apollo to store local data that is meant to carry from page to page (such as an e-commerce shopping cart). I would stick with Vuex for that.

Comment: Apollo can be used as a local store of data: https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/local-state.html

Comment: Oh hey! Didn't realize. Nice 

Answer (score 0):

You should create `.js` or `.ts` files with the corresponding `query` or `mutation`. Then, if you do not want to store the `state` in the **Apollo Client State Management System**, you can just call the corresponding service of state management in **Vue.js**. I am working with **React.js**, so what I would use in my case is the `Context API`, I am sure you can find the same thing for **Vue.js**.

Check out those links on how to implement `Context API` similar to **React.js**:

- [Context API for Vue.js/Nuxt.js applications](https://engineering.upgrad.com/context-api-for-vue-js-nuxt-js-applications-e4c984508bd1)
- [React context-like feature](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4029#)

Comment: I don't think vue has something like the context api although I am less familiar with React

Comment: i stored all the queries and mutations in one .js file and i can call them from my components using apolloClient.query(query:...) or using vue apollo, but still my issue is how can i put my state and mutations in centralized way so i can prevent repeating query and mutation codes for each of my components

Comment: I am sorry I cannot help you further. Graphql with React is on trend, easy, simple and an awesome combination. Hope someday you try React